# Line break(s) in the XML resulting file of sp_db_sendmail

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using sp_db_sendmail to send XML files as a direct result of a query.
The code is as below:

```
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max), @Vendor varchar(20)
set @Vendor='vcode'

SET @qry=' SET NOCOUNT ON; 
           select 
                 OrderHeader.No [OrderNo]
                ,OrderHeader.[Date] [OrderDate]
                ,OrderLines.[Line] [LineNo]
                ,OrderLines.[CrossRefNo] [Barcode]
                ,OrderLines.[UoM] [Unit]
                ,OrderLines.Quantity
                from dbo.OrderHeader 
                ....
            where OrderHeader.[Pay-to Vendor No_]=''' + @Vendor + ''' 
            order by OrderHeader.No, OrderLines.[Line]
            FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS,TYPE,ROOT(''Orders'')'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'SQLMailProfile',
  @recipients = 'myMailhere@somewhere.com',
  @body= 'A body here',
  @subject = 'A subject',
  @query = @qry,
  @query_attachment_filename='Orders.xml',
  @attach_query_result_as_file =1,
  @query_result_header=0,
  @query_no_truncate=1
```

Everything works OK apart from the resulting XML file, which at the 256 column it creates a line break thus ruining the XML document validity.

I searched a lot around the web and no solution came up, or at least I did not see one.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was one of the places you searched the documentation for [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx) which discusses the `@query_result_width` parameter which defaults to 256 characters?

Comment: Yes it was, and I'm looking for a way around this if possible. Thanks for the heads-up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no any reasons to send your resulting XML formatted as query result, you can sent it as email body. Email body is sent as is so your XML will not be corrupted. To make so you only need:

- Delare XML variable:

`DECLARE @myxml XML`

- Assign your query result to @myxml

`SELECT @myxml = (select 
                     OrderHeader.No [OrderNo]
                    ,OrderHeader.[Date] [OrderDate]
                    ,OrderLines.[Line] [LineNo]
                    ,OrderLines.[CrossRefNo] [Barcode]
                    ,OrderLines.[UoM] [Unit]
                    ,OrderLines.Quantity
                    from dbo.OrderHeader 
                    ....
                where OrderHeader.[Pay-to Vendor No_]=@Vendor 
                order by OrderHeader.No, OrderLines.[Line]
                FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS,TYPE,ROOT('Orders')
            )`

- Send result as email body:

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'SQLMailProfile',
      @recipients = 'myMailhere@somewhere.com',
      @body= CAST(@myxml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
      @subject = 'A subject',
      ...`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Serg. The thing is that I needed it as an attachment and not as a body to an e-mail. I managed to do it more efficiently and with much more granularity using SSIS. Thanks, anyway.